# Create RSACryptoServiceProvider from public key ONLY

Tags: c#, public-key, strongname, rsacryptoserviceprovider, strong-named-key

I am using the key-pair to sign my XML (using SignedXml) and I embed the public key in my app as embedded resources.

Here how I create the key pair

```
sn -k Warehouse.snk
sn -p Warehouse.snk WarehousePublic.snk
```

When I tried to read the `WarehousePublic.snk` I get an exception **Bad Version of provider.**

Here is my code:

```
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WareApp.Resources.WarehousePublic.snk"))
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        rsa.ImportCspBlob(bytes);  //the exception occurred here

        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create **RSACryptoServiceProvider** from public key only?

I have also tried to use X509Certificate2

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(bytes);  //I got exception here
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert2.PublicKey.Key;
```

But I get exception **Cannot find the requested object.**

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using `SN` to generate certificates for signing (using the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` at least) is unsupported. That would explain the error, I think. What you're looking for, in Windows, is a `.PFX` file (i.e. certificate with key) and `.CER` file (certificate without private key).

SN ([MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sn-exe-strong-name-tool)) doesn't provide security, and is only used for identity. You can use IIS or [`makecert.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3(VS.100).aspx) to generate a self-signed certificate that should work with what you're trying to do (i.e. a `.PFX` file and / or certificate already imported into the Windows certificate store). You can then extract the `.CER` file from that and use it for your project.

Comment: Hi Shaamaan, that is what I've tried (see my original question), but it doesn't work with error *Cannot find the requested object.*  :(

Comment: Oh, sorry @Sam, missed the second bit (wrote the answer from my phone).

Comment: @Sam Check my new answer - I've completely missed the problem (again, blaming my phone for this :P )

Answer (score 4):

I'll accepted Shaamaan answer because he is "***half***" right. You can actually use SN to sign certificate. `ImportCspBlob()` will work! However, when you tried to to import public key that generated using `sn -p Warehouse.snk WarehousePublic.snk`, it won't work.

In order to make it work, you need to generate public key in XML using `RSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXmlString(false)` and embed it as "embedded resources".

What I did is I create a console application. Just cut and paste my code below to generate public key in XML file.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length < 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Argument");
            Console.WriteLine("Usage:");
            Console.WriteLine("\tExtractPublicKey [Input SNK File] [Output XML File]");
            return;
        }

        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rsa.ImportCspBlob(bytes);
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(args[1], FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
                    sw.Write(rsa.ToXmlString(false));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After you compile it, to use the executable simply call:
`ExtractPublicKey.exe [SNK File with Private Key] [Output Public Key in XML File]`

To use the embedded certificate, simply do:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.FromXmlString(stream.ReadToEnd());
```

I hope this help someone that come across the similar problem.

Cheers

### UPDATED

Shaamaan answer should be followed. Please READ Shaamaan comment with MSDN link. He answer stands because he is not ONLY provide a correct way for security, but also inform me why SN is not right security tool. Thank you Shaamaan!

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. That said, [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sn-exe-strong-name-tool) itself lists the `SN` tool as not very good for security. Don't get me wrong, kudos for finding a way around that (and a +1 from me for this as well; you might also want to accept your own answer instead of mine), but I dare say using `makecert.exe` is probably the way to go... ;)

Comment: OMG! you are right!!! In that case your answer is absolutely right! Thanks Shaamaan!